# How do I use log4j with Maven and executable jar file?

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I'm trying to get log4j working in a simple application but I'm getting the message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
```

I execute the application with the command:

```
java -jar lunchtracker-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The log4j.properties file is in src/main/resources.  Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project <snip -- was messing up formatting>>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.uofitorn</groupId>
    <artifactId>lunchtracker</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>lunchtracker</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>net.uofitorn.LunchTrackerServer</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is my java code:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
<snip>
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LunchTrackerServer.class.getName());
logger.debug("Server started");
```

I think the problem is the log4j jar is not being included in my jar file.  When I unzip the jar I don't see it.  How do I get maven to include the log4j dependency in my jar?

Comment: I'm not 100% on this, but I believe you can include all necessary jars on the `java` command like this: `java -cp "lunchtracker-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;path-to-log4j-jar/log4j-1.2.16.jar" my.package.MainClass`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide `log4j` dependency at runtime, and to provide that you need to pack `log4j` artifact with your jar, [Here is how you can create fat jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to create a executable JAR with dependencies bundled.

There are several way to do.

Using [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies)

[Maven Shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html) is also another good choice

Answer (score 0):

When using maven for dependency management you should either use an IDE to add the dependencies to your classpath, or run your main class using maven exec:java goal maven exec plugin ( see http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html ).

To do that you need to specify your main class in the pom.xml and run it from the command line using the command:

```
mvn exec:java
```

Or run it from the command line directly:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="net.uofitorn.LunchTrackerServer"
```