# How to run a java file with a lot of jars dependencies in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, jar, terminal

I have a java class which has almost 12 jar file dependencies and i am using ubuntu 12.10 . I need to know how to run this java application because every time i run it , it gives me errors as "symbols not found". I have all jar files in a folder called libs. and i have tried these commands but none of these gives me some succesful result.I have flights.java class in test directory and libs directory is inside test directory.Currently i am in test directory

javac -cp "/home/ubuntu/test/libs/*.jar" flights.java

javac -cp '/home/ubuntu/test/libs/*.jar' flights.java

Answer (score 14):

if you have single class in your app called `flights.java` and all of your required jar are located at `/home/ubuntu/test/libs/` then use this

```
javac -cp '.:/home/ubuntu/test/libs/*.jar' flights.java
```

and to run

```
java -cp '.:/home/ubuntu/test/libs/*.jar' flights
```

better to just pack dependency and app in to a single jar and make it launchable and runnable jar

Comment: Can u please tell me how to go for using second option??

Comment: you would need a build tool for that, maven is very good here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven

Comment: This command "javac -cp '.:/home/ubuntu/test/libs/*.jar' flights.java "is giving me same error as earlier .

Comment: You don't write *.jar at the end. Just use * after the folder name. That is, use "java -cp .:/home/ubuntu/test/libs/* flights"

Comment: Problems frequently appear with compiling java files with different packages inside. Deleting them can **simplify** your **compiling** in **cmd**

Answer (score 5):

12 jars is not a very large number. Why not just append all the jars on the classpath?

Alternatively, you can create another jar and specify all the jars in Class-Path variable in that jar's MANIFEST.MF and then add this single jar to your classpath.

**EDIT:**

Here is how I would do it. Create a MANIFEST.MF file with content similar to this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0    
Archiver-Version: whatever  
Created-By: whatever  
Built-By: author-name  
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_34  
Class-Path: jar1.jar jar2.jar jar3.jar
```

replace `jar1.jar` with the actual file names of the jar.

Then you can create a jar with command : `jar cvf test.jar -m ./MANIFEST.MF` .

Now when you are using it on classpath use it like `java -jar xyz.jar class-name`

Comment: Can u please guide me step by step how to do a jar file containing all jar dependencies and then use this jar while giving javac command. Thanks in advance