# How do I check jar file dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I am coming from .NET background and I need to do some JAVA work these days. One thing I don't quite understand is how JAvA runtime resolve its jar dependencies. For example, I want to use javax.jcr to do some node adding. So I know I need to add these two dependencies because I need to use javax.jcr.Node and org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.JcrUtils.

```
      <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.jcr</groupId>
           <artifactId>jcr</artifactId>
           <version>2.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackrabbit-jcr-commons</artifactId>
           <version>2.8.0</version>
      </dependency>
          </dependency>
```

Now I passed the compilation but I get an exception in runtime. Then someone told me to add one more dependency which solves the problem.

```
         <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackrabbit-jcr2dav</artifactId>
               <version>2.6.0</version>
          </dependency>
```

From my understanding, jackrabbit-jcr-commons needs jackrabbit-jcr2dav to run.  If the jar misses a dependecy, how can it pass the compilation? And also how do I know I miss this particular dependency from jcr-common? This is a general question, it doesn't have to be specific to java jcr.

Comment: well exception occurs at runtime only

Comment: When the exception occurs, it is  looking for a class from a missing dependency, if the class is not included, how can the compilation pass?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java doesn't have any built-in way to declare dependencies between libraries. At runtime, when a class is needed, the Java ClassLoader tries to load it from all the jars in the classpath, and if the class is missing, then you get an exception. All the jars you need must be explicitly listed in the classpath. You can't just add one jar, and hope for Java to transitively load classes from this jar dependencies, because jar dependencies are a Maven concept, and not a Java concept. Nothing, BTW, forbids a library writer to compile 1000 interdependant classes at once, but put the compiled classes in 3 several different jars.

So what's left is Maven. I know nothing about JCR. But if a jar A published on Maven depends on a jar B published on Maven, then it should list B in its list of dependencies, and Maven should download B when it downloads A (and put both jars in the classpath).

The problem, however, is that some libraries have a loose dependency on other libraries. For example, Spring has native support for Hibernate. If you choose to use Spring with Hibernate, then you will need to explicitly declare Hibernate in your dependencies. But you could also choose to use Spring without Hibernate, and in that case you don't need to put Hibernate in the dependencies. Spring thus chooses to not declare Hibernate as one of its own dependencies, because Hibernate is not **always** necessary when using Spring.

In the end, it boils down to reading the documentation of the libraries you're using, to know which dependencies you need to add based on the features you use from these libraries.

Comment: if jar A needs a version 2.0 jar B as a "tight" dependency, and there are multiple version of jar B. When maven download jar A, will it auto resolve the version too? Same scenario, but now jar "B" is a "loose" dependency, will jar A's pom.xml states which version of jar "B" is needed?

Comment: First question: yes. Second question: the writer of the pom decides: he can choose not to list the dependency at all. He can also choose to list it as an optional dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Maven calculates transitive dependencies during compile-time, so compilation passes ok. The issue here is that, by default, maven won't build a proper `java -cp` command line to launch your application with all of its' dependencies (direct and transitive).

Two options to solve it:

1. Adjust your Maven project to build a "fat jar" -- jar which will include all needed classes from all dependencies. See SO answer with `pom.xml` snippet to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16222971/162634. Then you can launch by just `java -cp myfatjar.jar my.app.MainClass`
2. For multi-module project, with several result artifacts (that is, usually, different java programs) it makes sense to build custom `assembly.xml` which will tell Maven how to package your artifacts and which dependencies to include. You'll need to provide some kind of script in resulting package which will contain proper `java -cp ...` command. As far as I know, there's no "official" Maven plugin to build such a script during compilation/packaging.

There's free Maven [book](http://www.sonatype.com/resources/books/maven-the-complete-reference) which more or less explains how dependencies and assemblies work.

Answer (score 1):

Your question mixes Maven (a java-centric dependency resolution tool) and Java compile-time and run-time class-resolution. Both are quite different.

A Java .jar is, in simplified terms, a .zip file of Java .class files. During compilation, each Java source file, say MyClass.java, results in a Java bytecode file with the same name (MyClass.class). For compilation to be successful, all classes mentioned in a Java file must be available in the class-path at compile-time (but note that use of reflection and run-time class-name resolution, ala `Class.forName("MyOtherClass")` can avoid this entirely; also, you can use several class-loaders, which may be scoped independently of each other...).

However, after compilation, you do not need to place all your .class files together into the same Jar. Developers can split up their .class files between jars however they see fit. As long as a program that uses those jars only compile-time refers to and run-time loads classes that have all their dependencies compile-time and run-time available, you will not see any runtime errors. Classes in a .jar file are *not* recompiled when you compile a program that uses them; but, if any of their dependencies fails at run-time, you will get a run-time exception.

When using Maven, each maven artifact (typically a jar file) declares (in its `pom.xml` manifest file) the artifacts that it depends on. If it makes *any* sense to use `my-company:my-library-core` without needing `my-company:my-library-random-extension`, it is best practice to *not* make `-core` depend on `-random-extension`, although typically `-random-extension` will depend on `-core`. Any dependencies of an artifact that you depend on will be resolved and "brought in" when maven runs.

Also, from your question, a word of warning -- it is highly probable that `jackrabit-jcr2dav` version `2.6.0` expects to run alongside `jackrabbit-jcr-commons`  version `2.6.0`, and not `2.8.0`.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess (without spending too much time delving into the Maven hierarchies of this particular project), I believe your problem is caused by the fact that `jackrabbit-jcr-commons` has an optional dependency on `jackrabbit-api`.  That means that you will not automatically get that dependency (and it's dependencies) unless you re-declare it in your POM.

Generally speaking, optional dependencies are a band-aid solution to structural problems within a project.  To quote the maven documentation on the subject (http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html):

> Optional dependencies are used when it's not really possible (for
>   whatever reason) to split a project up into sub-modules. The idea is
>   that some of the dependencies are only used for certain features in
>   the project, and will not be needed if that feature isn't used.
>   Ideally, such a feature would be split into a sub-module that depended
>   on the core functionality project...this new subproject would have
>   only non-optional dependencies, since you'd need them all if you
>   decided to use the subproject's functionality.
>
> However, since the project cannot be split up (again, for whatever
>   reason), these dependencies are declared optional. If a user wants to
>   use functionality related to an optional dependency, they will have to
>   redeclare that optional dependency in their own project. This is not
>   the most clear way to handle this situation, but then again both
>   optional dependencies and dependency exclusions are stop-gap
>   solutions.

Generally speaking, exploring the POMs of your dependencies will reveal this kind of problem, though that process can be quite painful.