# Integrating slf4j with maven

Tags: java, maven

Hello guys I am new to Maven and I am trying to integrate slf4j in a maven project
Here is my pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
 <version>1.7.9</version>
</dependency>
```

And  I have these two lines in my main function

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);
logger.info("Hello World");
```

Project is compiled and packaged successfully but when I try to run it
through
java -cp target/maven-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.goutam.maven.App
The following Exception is thrown

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at com.goutam.maven.App.main(App.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like the idea of building fat jars, as we loose some flexibilities in this approach.

Rather would advocate for [copy-dependencies plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html) in maven.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
          <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
          <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
          <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Coupling it along with maven-jar-plugin. Read [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/manifest-customization.html) for details.

Assuming the third party dependencies are copied into target/lib folder.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>main class</mainClass>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

[build fat jar with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/how-to-build-fat-jar-with-maven)

add this to your `pom.xml`

```
<build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>

        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>assemble-all</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
```

and then run

```
java -cp target/maven-jar-with-dependencies-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.goutam.maven.App
```

note: pick the jar file which has `jar-with-dependencies`

Answer (score 2):

Maven will not by itself bundle all dependencies for you, so your resulting "maven-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" does not contains sl4j (nor any of its own dependencies).

If you want your command line to work, you need to include all the librairies inside your jar. This can be achieved using the [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) with something like:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>org.sample.App</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id> 
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two other answers recommend `maven-assembly-plugin`. I think you're generally better served with the [`maven-shade-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html).

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- put your configurations here -->
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```