# Spark/Java: NoClassDefFoundError in GSON dependency

Tags: java, apache-spark, gson, maven-3

I have a small Spark project using a JAR file, which I am packaging with Maven.

I am using GSON to work with JSON files, and I specifically need the JsonReader class.

I added the GSON dependency, and when I run it as a standard Java project it works fine. However, when I package it and run it in Spark it complains:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader
```

Here is the line in question:

```
reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(
                jsonfile)));
```

I did import it:

```
import com.google.gson.*;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
```

Here is my POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SWETesting</groupId>
  <artifactId>SWETesting</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source/>
          <target/>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I even installed libgoogle-gson in my distribution, but that didn't help.

What is the problem here?

Edit: I am submitting the job in standalone mode after building it with Maven:

```
mvn package
/home/chris/Tools/spark-1.2.1/bin/spark-submit --class PlagiarismCheck --master local[6] target/SWETesting-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar > output.txt
```

Comment: How do you submit your spark job? Could you show us your code completely?

Comment: Added the command that launches Spark. Not sure how showing more code will help as it's not an issue in Eclipse itself, just when I try to launch it in Spark. I don't have Eclipse set up to run it on the Spark server directly.

Comment: I think the problem is that your project dependencies aren't included within `SWETesting-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, hence the error. I would try generating a fat jar using `maven-assembly` plugin or similar.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that, I'm very new to Maven and can't do much more than mvn package at the moment.

Comment: @jarandaf I got it working by following your advice, thanks. You mind phrasing that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your project dependencies aren't included within `SWETesting-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, hence the error. You can generate a fat jar using [maven-assembly](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) plugin or similar, that should fix the issue. You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/how-to-build-fat-jar-with-maven).

Comment: Thanks! Works great. I used the code from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16222971/2300708

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is referring to the old version of jar. gson jar old version 1.5 doesn't have the package name stream. Check the maven dependency tree and find if any older versions of gson jar exists. If yes clean the project/ remove the jars in the repository

Command to check the maven dependency tree

```
C:\Projects\Project_name>mvn dependency:tree
```

Comment: It says: com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.3.1:compile. So it's a new version. I also cleaned it with mvn clean, didn't help.