# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpException on AWS EC2 ubuntu instance

Tags: java, maven, amazon-ec2

I am new to java and maven. I am trying to run a project that I deployed on EC2 but I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     org/apache/http/HttpException
    at TripBuddy.DataCollectorDaemon.App.main(App.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

I have the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
       <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
       <version>4.0-alpha4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
       <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
       <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I changed the version of the first dependency to a later one(4.0 , 4.1.1, 4.3) and then the code doesnt build.  I get error: exception URISyntaxException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

Comment: It's nearly always a bad idea to mix major versions like that. Why are you trying to include both of them?

Comment: As you also pointed out, there is already a 4.4 release so I recommend upgrading your version to that one. If your code doesn't compile, please post it so we can help you to fix that.

Comment: The `exception URISyntaxException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement` means that you can just scrap that exception from the catch block (and maybe the complete `try`/`catch` block).

Comment: I tried to use the latest version of HttpComponents, and got the build error, so took out the try catch block and the build was successful but on running it I still get the "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/HttpClient""

Comment: maybe you need to bundle the dependencies like HttpComponents in your jar, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/how-to-build-fat-jar-with-maven

Comment: Using the shade plugin worked!! Thank you