# Maven JAR lib directory location

Tags: maven

I've recently been learning Maven, and I'm trying to understand where the 'lib' directory should be in a JAR that maven builds. When I open the JAR, I don't see any of the libraries that my application needs to run.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to build fat jar with Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/how-to-build-fat-jar-with-maven)

Comment: This isn't something maven does by default, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23937311/4855700 for how to set it up.