# Adding jars to a spark app

Tags: jar, apache-spark

Current when I run spark-submit I provide a whole bunch to paths of jars followed by the '--jars' option:

```
./spark\-submit --class "AppName" --master spark://server24:7077 --jars /path1.jar,path2.jar,path3.jar /pathAppName_2.10-1.0.jar arg1 arg2
```

Is there a cleaner way to include the jars files followed by --jar in the command above?

I tried adding them to spark.driver.extraClassPath in spark-defaults.conf but that does not seem to help. Couldn't find anything in the spark documentation otherwise.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify jars that you depend on when creating a SparkContext:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
             .setMaster('local[*]')
             .setAppName('example')
             .setJars(Array('/path/to/dependencies/first.jar',
                            '/path/to/dependencies/second.jar'))

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

This is basically what's happening under the covers when you use the --jars argument of spark-submit.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this in my Java Spark app was by using the maven shade plugin to create a fat-packed jar with all of the external dependencies in it. Otherwise, if you're using scala, [this link](http://blog.prabeeshk.com/blog/2014/04/08/creating-uber-jar-for-spark-project-using-sbt-assembly/) may help you. For java, I would reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/how-to-build-fat-jar-with-maven).

In terms of another method of doing this out of the box with Spark, I don't think there's a cleaner way - at least if there is I never found one.