# Export a Jar error with JDateChooser

Tags: java, swing, jar, rmi, executable-jar

First time that I have written a program in Java SWING with RMI Connection. I have exported the JAR for the Client and works really nice but when I m trying to open a specific JFrame/window, it doesnt do nothing and I m receiving the following Error Messages

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/toedt
er/calendar/JDateChooser
        at clientValantis.MenuPage$2.actionPerformed(MenuPage.java:66)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionP
rivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionP
rivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionP
rivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 37 more
```

The Jframe/Window that my program opened using a JDateChooser and I think this is the Problem. I dont what I have to change so the JFrame open. When I m runnig the program in the Eclipse dont have this Error Messages.It works really good . Has to do with the Build Path ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the Jar file which contains com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser (probably jcalendar-1.X.jar).
You can create a "fat" jar using eclipse or add your Jar dependencies to the execution classpath like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath).
One option is to use [Fat Jar Eclipse Plug-In](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/), another is to create it using Maven like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/how-to-build-fat-jar-with-maven).

Comment: How can I create this fat jar ...because I thought I have include all the jar that are in my build path of the project