# How to automatically collect all related class into one jar (use maven)?

Tags: java, maven, jar, build, dependencies

I have a class ClassA in package packageA and ClassA import ClassB in packageB.(in fact ClassA import a lot of java file)

Then the directory is ：

```
root
     pom.xml
     src 
             packageA
                      classA
                      pom.xml
             packageB
                      classB
```

My goal is to generate a jar include classA and classB by only telling maven that I input classA.

the pom.xml in the root directory is like

```
<groupId>org.abc</groupId>
<artifactId>all-code</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>\src\packageA</module>
</modules>
<name>helloworld</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

the pom.xml in the packageA directory is like

```
<parent>
    <relativePath>..\..\</relativePath>
    <artifactId>all-code</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.abc</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>client-code</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>client</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>client</classifier>
                        <includes>
                            <include>packageB\*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>                               <!--it doesn't work-->
    </plugins>
    <sourceDirectory>.</sourceDirectory>        <!--it works-->
</build>
```

And the error message is  `package does not exist`

I read the question here and try it.
[Building a fat jar using maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven)
And I think the link question is to achieve that the asker want to include external jars into one jar . But I want to include my own classB into one jar ,while I only input classA to maven ,and let maven find classB because classA import classB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building a fat jar using maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven)

Comment: @MrWiggles thank you for attention for this question .But after I tried the answer of the link , I find it does include all the external jar into one jar.But it doesn't import the class of my own that I want

Comment: Have you included your packageB as a dependency in packageA?

Comment: @MrWiggles sorry I am new to maven ,I only know how to add a local jar to dependency .              <dependency>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>.jar</systemPath>
   <groupId></groupId>
   <artifactId></artifactId>
   <version></version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Yes,I feel I 'm near to the goal.Now that the jar just doesn't include local system files<dependency>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>path</systemPath>
   <groupId></groupId>
   <artifactId></artifactId>
   <version></version>
   <type>java-source</type>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I write a program myself to solve this problem

http://blog.csdn.net/guotong1988/article/details/50265463