# Maven , How to add dependency of local system java-source?

Tags: java, maven, jar, build, dependencies

I want to build one jar that includes a child module which depends on other package of my own project.

The output one jar should include all the related class (both from jar and my own project's classes).So the child module's classes is the base classes that should be included in the output jar,and these import some classes of my own project.All the related classes in my own project should be included.

for more detail please visit [How to automatically collect all related class into one jar (use maven)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063105/how-to-automatically-collect-all-related-class-into-one-jar-use-maven)

Here is what I already find:

```
  <project>
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>D:\how\to\write</systemPath>
        <groupId>how.to.write</groupId>
        <artifactId>how-to-write</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>java-source</type>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
 </project>
```

The error message is :  `Could not find artifact how.to.write:how-to-write:jar:sources:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT at specified path D:\how\to\write`

the path `D:\how\to\write` contains my own project's classes that could support the build

Comment: D:\how\to\write should contain a `how.to.write:how-to-write:jar:sources:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` . Do you have it? Or just you have only class files in that location?\

Comment: @localhost999 Thank you ,  I have only class files in that location . I don't know how to let maven find the classes..

Comment: is `how.to.write` a maven project? Then do a `mvn clean install`

Answer (score 0):

Your maven dependency will look for a jar file with name `how.to.write:how-to-write:jar:sources:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` in `D:\how\to\write` directory. Since you do not have one, the build will fail.

If your own project does not use `maven`, then you should create a `jar` file and place it in `D:\how\to\write` location and rename it to `how.to.write:how-to-write:jar:sources:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`. Then your build `mvn clean install` will be success.

The command for creating jar file is `jar cf jar-file input-file(s)`.
Have a look at this [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) on how to create a jar file

Comment: Thank you. But in fact I could build it successfully in this way <dependency>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>.jar</systemPath>
   <groupId></groupId>
   <artifactId></artifactId>
   <version></version>
   <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>  Do you know how to let the local system jar be included into the output jar?

Comment: OK. Try ading this plugin to your `pom.xml`. `<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>`  and build the project

Comment: you know, if I don't add  <build><sourceDirectory>.</sourceDirectory></build>  it will not build any thing.But if I add<build><sourceDirectory>.</sourceDirectory></build>,the output jar only contains the <sourceDirectory>'s path's classes and the dependencies of maven repo without my jar of local system path