# How to use jenkins to take a module maven project and turn it into a .jar

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

So I'm working on a java project located [here](https://github.com/Civcraft/NameLayer).  I have it on a [jenkins server](http://build.civcraft.co:8080/view/Latest/job/NameLayer-master/) and I want it to compile all the different modules under one jar.  I tried copying what another project did but am unable to produce a jar so I believe it has something to do with how I need to configure jenkins in order for it to make the jar.  The jar doesn't need to be executable.

Answer (score 0):

The maven-assembly-plugin can create your jar: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

Your project has 4 JARs and they don't depend on each other.
If `NameLayer` depends on `NameLayer1_8_R1` you have to

- add the dependency `NameLayer1_8_R1` to the `pom.xml` of `NameLayer` and
- the `maven-assembly-plugin` as descrbibed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven) to create a fat JAR (including all depending JARs).

  Do the first step for as many dependencies as you need.

Comment: I got that far, now I'm at a point where it works when I build locally how I want it but jenkins sees that the project has modules but won't follow what the pom says.