# Netbeans 8.0.2 Maven Dependencies

Tags: maven, netbeans, netbeans-8, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a Netbeans 8.0.2 Java project using Maven. I wish to produce a JAR with all dependencies included. I have seen similar questions but none of which seem to have a the solution that said I am new to it.

This is what i have added to the pom.xml (excluding dependencies etc.) from what I have read online but still no luck.

> ```
> <properties>
>      <mainClass>com.oss.nia.startup</mainClass>
> </properties>
>
> <build>
>     <plugins>
> <plugin>
>     <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
>     <executions>
>         <execution>
>             <phase>install</phase>
>             <goals>
>                 <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
>             </goals>
>             <configuration>
>                 <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
>             </configuration>
>         </execution>
>     </executions>
> </plugin>
> <plugin>
>     <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
>     <configuration>
>         <archive>
>             <manifest>
>                 <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
>                 <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
>                 <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
>             </manifest>
>         </archive>
>     </configuration>
> </plugin>
>     </plugins>
> </build>
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building a fat jar using maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven)

Comment: You could use Spring-Boot, which handles that for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/27185508/1329813