# JavaFX Spring ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, maven, javafx

I want to build a runnable jar for a JavaFX application which uses depency injection (Spring framework libraries) to manage multiple FXMl files and multiple FXMLDocumentControllers.
However, when exeuting the jar a "ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext" is reported. 
Yet, I have added Spring library (3.2.7) to the project in Netbeans and it functions well within the IDE.
How can I assure, that the above class is available in the jar as well?

[image: jar execution error listing]

Comment: Since you're using maven, could you share the dependency definition to spring-context that you have added to your pom.xml? The tag is added to the question, but I have to ask: are you using maven for packaging your jar?

Comment: @deepdownunder2222 You are absolutely right. I was wondering if perhaps I have to use Maven to solve this problem? So I added the tag. Is it obligatory to use Maven in this context, and what would I have to write where in the pom.xml? (I'm sorry for being so unexperienced with maven and dependency management)

Comment: You could create a fat jar from it, including the necessary classes.

Comment: The recognized way to create a jar file for an FX application is to use the FX packaging tools: see the [deployment documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/). Both the `javapackager -createjar` command and the ant tasks have options for including external jar files. This is also automated via Netbeans (which I don't use, so I don't know the details), but the linked documentation says this should happen via the project properties.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling and packaging your code, the resulting jar usually only contains **YOUR** code. You need to add the dependent jar files to the classpath. What that means is, whenever you invoke `java -jar yourapp.jar some.package.MainClass` to run your application, you need to list all required jar files in the `-cp` option of the java command.

Another (bad) solution could be to use maven's assembly plugin (or some other means) to create a fat-jar, which essentially is a merge of `yourapp.jar` and all dependent jars.

Read: [Building a fat jar using maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven)

Comment: Note that there are [specific tools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/) for creating jar files for JavaFX applications.