# Adding external jar files to my repository or project without maven install command

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am looking forward to an solution to my current problem with maven and my IDE Intellij Idea 16. I have got around 100-150 different libraries from my customer, which I need to include to my maven project. It is a lot of work to the maven install-plugin command 150 times. I already included them into my IDEs project as external dependency.

Is there any solution to integrate them easily into my repository without 150 times typing of the install-command?

How can IntelliJ Idea help me to integrate them? I've googled so far, but no usefull results.

Comment: Maybe related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven

Comment: If you are using Maven, you should let it bundle in the dependencies, not the IDE

Comment: Currently I cant build my jar file - because my local maven repo does not know around 150 external libraries. Now I need them to integrate in my local maven repository to build my project, but I dont want to "install" them 150 times...as less as possible :)

Comment: You should be able to declare a `libs` folder to move your jar files, and maven will include them all. I'm not sure I follow what you mean by running the install command.

Comment: Write a bash script to upload them to your company's nexus. It has a rest api and is quite easy to do using curl. It should only take a few lines of code and shouldn't take you more than 10 minutes or so to write, even if you're not familiar with bash.