# Why jar crated by maven has no libs from dependencies

Tags: java, maven

So i have this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180130</version>
</dependency>
```

and after

> mvn package

when i run jar i get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject
```

when i run my app in intellij everything works perfectly, the problem is that maven is not including libs from dependencies into final jar.

Is there any solution for this problem?

**EDIT - full pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>JavaProjekt</groupId>
<artifactId>JavaProjekt</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180130</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>
```

Comment: Please add whole pom.xml to the question. Maven doesn't include dependencies into final jar by default

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16222748/2970947

Comment: Please provide the whole stacktrace. An exception has to be interpreted according to the context.

Comment: You have to create an uber jar. Use maven shade plugin

Comment: When maven runs your jar it adds the jars you reference to the class path. You could do the same or look into shading.

Comment: U need to create a "fat" jar. Which is a jar that include dependencies. By default, it only build the files you write and 3rd party jars are simply added to the classpath and expect to be there are runtime. See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven

Comment: Please don't include answers in the question; add an answer and accept it. Self-answering questions is perfectly okay, and helps prevent confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>JavaProjekt</groupId>
<artifactId>JavaProjekt</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>app.App</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <shadedClassifierName>launcher</shadedClassifierName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180130</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.11</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>
```

and run by

> java -jar target/JavaProjekt-1.0-SNAPSHOT-launcher.jar