# Apache Livy cURL not working for spark-submit command

Tags: scala, apache-spark, curl, hdfs, livy

I recently started working with Spark Scala, HDFS, sbt and Livy. Currently I tried to create livy batch.

```
Warning: Skip remote jar hdfs://localhost:9001/jar/project.jar.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SimpleApp
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:225)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:686)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

This is the error statement, showing in livy batch log.

My spark-submit command is working perfectly fine for local .jar file.

```
spark-submit --class "SimpleApp" --master local target/scala-2.11/simple-project_2.11-1.0.jar
```

But same for livy (in cURL) it is throwing error.

```
"requirement failed: Local path /target/scala-2.11/simple-project_2.11-1.0.jar cannot be added to user sessions."
```

So, I shift .jar file in hdfs. My new code for livy is -

```
curl -X POST --data '{
    "file": "/jar/project.jar",
    "className": "SimpleApp",
    "args": ["ddd"]
}'  
-H 
"Content-Type: application/json" 
http://server:8998/batches
```

This is throwing error which is mention above.

Please let me know, where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
hdfs://localhost:9001/jar/project.jar.
```

It's expecting your jar file located on **hdfs**.

If it's local, maybe you should try to specify protocol in a path, or just upload that into hdfs:

```
 "file": "file:///absolute_path/jar/project.jar",
```

Comment: Okay and what is the solution for ClassNotFoundException?

Comment: Jar that contains that class can’t be found, as soon as you provide correct path to class issue should be resolved.

Comment: In jar file class is in spark/wordcount folder, I tried spark.wordcount.SimpleApp as class name but still throwing ClassNotFoundException

Comment: did you solve issue with path to jar file? is error message the same?

Comment: I have uploaded jar file in hdfs, but error still same.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a `fat jar` file with your codebase + necessary jar - `sbt assembly` or use [maven plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16222971/6860682), upload this jar file to `HDFS` and run `spark-submit` with this jar file which is placed on HDFS or you can use `cURL` as well.

Steps with `Scala/Java`:

1. Make fat jar with SBT/Maven or whatever.
2. Upload fat jar to `HDFS`
3. Use `cURL` for submitting jobs:

`curl -X POST --data '{  //your data should be here}' -H "Content-Type: plication/json"  your_ip:8998/batches`

If you don't want to make a fat jar file and upload it to HDFS, you can consider python scripts, it could be submitted like a plain text without any jar file.

The example with plain python code:

`curl your_ip:8998/sessions/0/statements -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"code":"print(\"asdf\")"}'`

In data body, you have to send valid Python code.
It's a way in which tools like `Jupyter Notebook/Torch` works.

Also, I made one more [example](https://gist.github.com/arukavytsia/f2dd13ce80d3a32fb38c363984d0185c) with Livy and Python.
For checking results:

`curl your_ip:8998/sessions/0/statements/1`

As I mentioned above, for Scala/Java fat jar and uploading to HDFS are required.

Comment: I have created fat jar, as per your instruction and uploaded to HDFS but problem statement still same, jar file still work with local path i.e. 
"spark-submit --class "SimpleApp" --master local myProject/target/scala-2.11/SimpleProject-assembly-1.0.jar"
but doesn't work with HDFS path i.e.
"spark-submit --class "SimpleApp" --master local hdfs://localhost:9001/jar/SimpleProject-assembly-1.0.jar"

Comment: @Divine You specified `local` for the path to HDFS - it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To use local files for `livy` batch jobs you need to add the local folder to the `livy.file.local-dir-whitelist` property in `livy.conf`.

Description from `livy.conf.template`:

> List of local directories from where files are allowed to be added to user sessions. By default it's empty, meaning users can only reference remote URIs when starting their sessions.