# Apache Livy doesn't work with local jar file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, livy

I am trying to run local jar file with spark-submit which is working perfectly fine. Here is the command-

```
spark-submit --class "SimpleApp" --master local myProject/target/scala-2.11/simple-project_2.11-1.0.jar
```

But when I am trying with curl

```
curl -X POST --data '{
 "file": "file:///home/user/myProject/target/scala-2.11/simple-project_2.11-1.0.jar",
 "className": "SimpleApp",
}'  
-H 
"Content-Type: application/json" 
http://server:8998/batches
```

It is throwing error

```
"requirement failed: Local path /home/user/myProject/target/scala-2.11/simple-project_2.11-1.0.jar cannot be added to user sessions."
```

Here is my livy.conf file, as some article suggest to change few things.

```
# What host address to start the server on. By default, Livy will bind to all network interfaces.
livy.server.host = 0.0.0.0

# What port to start the server on.
livy.server.port = 8998

# What spark master Livy sessions should use.
livy.spark.master = local

# What spark deploy mode Livy sessions should use.
livy.spark.deploy-mode = client

# List of local directories from where files are allowed to be added to user sessions. By
# default it's empty, meaning users can only reference remote URIs when starting their
# sessions.
livy.file.local-dir-whitelist= /home/user/.livy-sessions/
```

Please help me out with this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recently got the solution of local file reading from Apache Livy as I was creating the wrong request with cURL. I just replaced file reading protocol from 'file://' with 'local:/' and that works for me.

```
curl -X POST --data '{
  "file": "local:/home/user/myProject/target/scala-2.11/simple-project_2.11-1.0.jar",
  "className": "SimpleApp",
}'  
-H 
"Content-Type: application/json" 
http://server:8998/batches
```

That was quite a small mistake but still, my jar file cannot be accessed from HDFS.

Thank you all for helping out.

Comment: Thank you for the tip of adding 'local'.

Answer (score 0):

Presence of `Apache Livy` jar file is the mandatory requirement. It wouldn't work without the corresponding jar file.

My advice is next: just append `livy jar` file to classpath with `java's cp option`:

```
java -cp /usr/local/livy.jar com.myclass.Main
```

or simply use SBT:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.livy" % "livy-api" % "0.4.0-incubating"
```

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.livy</groupId>
    <artifactId>livy-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.0-incubating</version>
</dependency>
```

Or your favorite build tool.

BTW, you also can upload `livy jar` file to `HDFS` and use it on your Hadoop cluster, it can significantly simplify your life.

Comment: I tried with hdfs as well but I still had issues with that. You can check my query here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50969333/apache-livy-curl-not-working-for-spark-submit-command

Comment: You have to make `fat jar` file with your codebase + necessary jar - `sbt assembly` or some maven plugin, upload this jar file to `hdfs` and run `spark-submit` with this jar file which is placed on `hdfs` or use `curl` as well.

Comment: If you don't want to make a fat jar file and upload it to hdfs, you can consider python scripts, it could be submitted like a plain text withou any jar file.

Comment: @Divine I've provided the answer to your another question in details, please, check it.

Answer (score 0):

The below answer worked for me as stated in here
[Apache Livy cURL not working for spark-submit command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50969333/apache-livy-curl-not-working-for-spark-submit-command)

To use local files for livy batch jobs you need to add the local folder to the livy.file.local-dir-whitelist property in livy.conf.

Description from livy.conf.template:

List of local directories from where files are allowed to be added to user sessions. By default it's empty, meaning users can only reference remote URIs when starting their sessions.