# jackson/guava jar conflict when run spark on yarn

Tags: scala, apache-spark, classpath, spark-submit

My Spark environment is scala 2.10.5, spark1.6.0, hadoop2.6.0.
The application uses jackson to do some serialization/deserialzation things. 
when submit to spark(yarn client mode):

```
spark-submit --class noce.train.Train_Grid --master yarn-client --num-executors 10 --executor-cores 2 --driver-memory 10g --executor-memory 12g --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2048 \
             --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=./guava-15.0.jar:./jackson-annotations-2.4.4.jar:./jackson-core-2.4.4.jar:./jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar:./jackson-module-scala_2.10-2.4.4.jar \
             --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/home/ck/lib/guava-15.0.jar:/home/ck/lib/jackson-annotations-2.4.4.jar:/home/ck/lib/jackson-core-2.4.4.jar:/home/ck/lib/jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar:/home/ck/lib/jackson-module-scala_2.10-2.4.4.jar \
             --jars /home/ck/lib/guava-15.0.jar,/home/ck/lib/jackson-annotations-2.4.4.jar,/home/ck/lib/jackson-core-2.4.4.jar,/home/ck/lib/jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar,/home/ck/lib/jackson-module-scala_2.10-2.4.4.jar \
         /home/ck/gnoce_scala.jar
```

I got errors:

```
18/09/12 09:46:47 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 39.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 893, host-9-138): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class noce.grid.Grid$
    at noce.train.Train_Grid$$anonfun$3.apply(Train_Grid.scala:80)
    at noce.train.Train_Grid$$anonfun$3.apply(Train_Grid.scala:79)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

18/09/12 09:46:47 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 198.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 897) on executor host-9-136: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError (Could not initialize class noce.grid.Grid$) [duplicate 1]
18/09/12 09:46:47 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 58.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 890, host-9-136): java.lang.AbstractMethodError: noce.grid.Grid$$anon$1.com$fasterxml$jackson$module$scala$experimental$ScalaObjectMapper$_setter_$com$fasterxml$jackson$module$scala$experimental$ScalaObjectMapper$$typeCache_$eq(Lorg/spark-project/guava/cache/LoadingCache;)V
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper$class.$init$(ScalaObjectMapper.scala:50)
    at noce.grid.Grid$$anon$1.<init>(Grid.scala:75)
    at noce.grid.Grid$.<init>(Grid.scala:75)
    at noce.grid.Grid$.<clinit>(Grid.scala)
    at noce.train.Train_Grid$$anonfun$3.apply(Train_Grid.scala:80)
    at noce.train.Train_Grid$$anonfun$3.apply(Train_Grid.scala:79)
... ...
```

The code is as follows:

```
//Train_Grid.scala
val newGridData: RDD[(Long, Grid)] = data.map(nr => {  //line 79
  val grid = Grid(nr)                                  //line 80
  (grid.id, grid)
}).reduceByKey(_.merge(_)) 

//Grid.scala
object Grid {
  val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper  //line 75
  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
  mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
```

I print the class paths in driver:

```
val cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader
cl.asInstanceOf[java.net.URLClassLoader].getURLs.take(20).foreach(println)

file:/home/ck/lib/guava-15.0.jar
file:/home/ck/lib/jackson-annotations-2.4.4.jar
file:/home/ck/lib/jackson-core-2.4.4.jar
file:/home/ck/lib/jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar
file:/home/ck/lib/jackson-module-scala_2.10-2.4.4.jar
file:/etc/spark/conf.cloudera.spark_on_yarn/
file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.p0.18/jars/spark-assembly-1.6.0-cdh5.7.2-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.7.2.jar
file:/etc/spark/conf.cloudera.spark_on_yarn/yarn-conf/
file:/etc/hive/conf.cloudera.hive/
file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.p0.18/jars/ST4-4.0.4.jar
file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.p0.18/jars/accumulo-core-1.6.0.jar
file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.p0.18/jars/accumulo-fate-1.6.0.jar
file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.p0.18/jars/accumulo-start-1.6.0.jar
file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.p0.18/jars/accumulo-trace-1.6.0.jar
file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.p0.18/jars/activation-1.1.jar
file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.p0.18/jars/ant-1.9.1.jar
file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.p0.18/jars/ant-launcher-1.9.1.jar
file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.p0.18/jars/antisamy-1.4.3.jar
file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.p0.18/jars/antlr-2.7.7.jar
file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.p0.18/jars/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
```

and executors:

```
val x = sc.parallelize(0 to 1, 2)
val p = x.flatMap { i =>
  val cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader
  cl.asInstanceOf[java.net.URLClassLoader].getURLs.take(20).map(_.toString)
}
p.collect().foreach(println)

file:/DATA2/yarn/nm/usercache/ck/appcache/application_1533542623806_5351/container_1533542623806_5351_01_000007/guava-15.0.jar
file:/DATA2/yarn/nm/usercache/ck/appcache/application_1533542623806_5351/container_1533542623806_5351_01_000007/jackson-annotations-2.4.4.jar
file:/DATA2/yarn/nm/usercache/ck/appcache/application_1533542623806_5351/container_1533542623806_5351_01_000007/jackson-core-2.4.4.jar
file:/DATA2/yarn/nm/usercache/ck/appcache/application_1533542623806_5351/container_1533542623806_5351_01_000007/jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar
file:/DATA2/yarn/nm/usercache/ck/appcache/application_1533542623806_5351/container_1533542623806_5351_01_000007/jackson-module-scala_2.10-2.4.4.jar
file:/DATA2/yarn/nm/usercache/ck/appcache/application_1533542623806_5351/container_1533542623806_5351_01_000007/
file:/DATA7/yarn/nm/usercache/ck/filecache/745/__spark_conf__2134162299477543917.zip/
file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.p0.18/jars/spark-assembly-1.6.0-cdh5.7.2-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.7.2.jar
file:/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn/
file:/var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/2147-yarn-NODEMANAGER/
file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.p0.18/jars/parquet-column-1.5.0-cdh5.7.2.jar
file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.p0.18/jars/parquet-format-2.1.0-cdh5.7.2-sources.jar
file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.p0.18/jars/parquet-jackson-1.5.0-cdh5.7.2.jar
file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.p0.18/jars/parquet-scala_2.10-1.5.0-cdh5.7.2.jar
file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.p0.18/jars/parquet-hadoop-1.5.0-cdh5.7.2.jar
file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.p0.18/jars/hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.7.2.jar
file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.p0.18/jars/parquet-avro-1.5.0-cdh5.7.2.jar
file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.p0.18/jars/hadoop-auth-2.6.0-cdh5.7.2.jar
file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.p0.18/jars/hadoop-aws-2.6.0-cdh5.7.2.jar
file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.2-1.cdh5.7.2.p0.18/jars/hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.7.2-tests.jar
... ...
```

But obviously, it still use the incorrect guava version(org.spark-project.guava.cache.LoadingCache)

And if I set spark.{driver, executor}.userClassPathFirst to true, I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.maxCompressedLength(I)I
```

so, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Few things I would suggest for you.

First you should create a `fat jar` for your project. If you are using Maven just use follow this question here: [Building a fat jar using maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven)

Or if you are using SBT you can use the SBT Assembly as well: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

That will help you to not send all the jars in the `spark-submit` line of code. And will allow you to use `shading` at your code.

Shade allows you to use the same library in your code with different version without any conflict with the framework library. To use that please follow the instructions for:

**Maven** - https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

**SBT** - https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#shading

So for you case, you should shade your `guava` classes. I have this problem with the `protobuf` classes in my Spark Project and I use the shade plugin with maven like this:

```
<build>
    <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>com.google.protobuf</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>shaded.com.google.protobuf</shadedPattern>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```