# Intellij Apache Ignite Project won't generate a working JAR File

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, ignite

My Intellij project is running flawlessly inside the IDE but any methods that attempted to extract a valid .jar file from it resulted in some kind of error.
My project uses Maven, Spring and Apache Ignite.
Here's my `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-gettings-started</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
            <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-indexing</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

The manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: server.ServerNodeExample
```

And, the folder structure:

```
- project
  - .idea
  - out
  - src
    - main
      - java
        - examples
          - ...
        - server
          - ...
      - resources
        - META-INF
          - MANIFEST.MF
    - test
  - target
  - pom.xml
```

I list the attempts below:

1 - Running `mvn clean install` in the `pom.xml` directory: compiled fine, but I get the error `no main manifest attribute` relative to my jar file.

2 - I opened the jar file and the manifest there was quite different:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: evandro.teixeira
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_191
```

So i appended this line to it:

```
Main-Class: server.ServerNodeExample
```

And now I find myself stuck in this weird exception:

```
  :$ java -jar ignite-gettings-started-1.0.0.jar 
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ignite/IgniteException
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
  at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.IgniteException
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  ... 7 more
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Two things: you can configure main class in pom.xml and second when running jar you still need to include all dependencies to classpath.

Comment: This also worked, but i judged the fat jar to be the simpler approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to build a [fat jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven) if you want to be able to run your project with `java -jar`. This does not depend on the nature of your dependencies as long as you have any of them.

You could also try and use Spring Boot which will do a fat jar for you.

And I do not recommend using Apache Ignite 2.1 since it's very old and Apache Ignite 2.7 should be already out when you figure out how to launch your project.

Comment: The `spring-boot-maven-plugin` worked like a charm and simplified my `pom.xml` dramatically.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that with Apache Ignite, Spring Boot may cause problems if you do not peg `h2` version to whatever exact version that Apache Ignite depents on. You've been warned!