# itext7 Hello World example with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: maven, itext, itext7

I'm using maven on centos 7, and starting with *iText7*.
I followed the tutorial editing the pom file and Hello World project, but when I type

```
java -cp target/xxx-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.itext.app.App
```

I got

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/itextpdf/layout/element/IBlockElement

Because I'm new to create Java project on linux, so I can't figure out where might be the problem.

[image: Error message]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please tell us which tutorial you are following. Please add your code and the pom file after your changes

Comment: @UladzimirAsipchuk Hi, I've added the pom file and the code. The tutorial is on the website, as I remembered, the name is HelloWorld2.java

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run from a built jar file.  Is the jar file a fat jar? If not, it won't have iText on the classpath at runtime, and you would need to add those to the classpath when you add the built jar.

Comment: Hi @BenIngle, doesn't Maven will automatically download the jar file if I write the pom file? From my understanding...(I'm new to use maven with command)

Comment: By default, Maven does not include dependencies in the jar.  There are a number of plugins that do this for you though, most notably the Maven Assembly plugin and the Shade plugin.  Check this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is your runtime jar does not include bundled iText, and iText is not being added to your classpath. Two options:

1. Use Maven Assembly or Shade plugin to bundle a fat/uber jar.  Maven does not bundle dependencies by default.  By using one of these plugins, Maven will produce a jar that includes all dependencies that are specified in your POM. Then you can run your application with the same command line. See this SO question for details: [Building a fat jar using maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven)
2. Add iText to the classpath at runtime. Your command line would look like this:

`java -cp /path/to/iText-7/;target/xxx-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.itext.app.App`

Comment: As I mentioned, my command is: java -cp target/xxx-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.itext.app.App, which seems is similar to your second method. But I'll try the other method, anyway, thanks!

Comment: Hi @BenIngle, I tried your first solution and it worked perfectly!! Thanks for your advice. I was first thinking that the problem is due to itext library, but it seems to be dependency problem. Although I still not figure out how to correctly compile with second method, but the first method totally work!

Comment: Glad I could help. For the second option, Java doesn't know about iText in your original question because Maven didn't put the iText jars in the build jar, and you didn't tell Java where to find it.  My second solution tells Java where to find your iText jars that you either download manually from iText's website, or Maven downloads for you.  Check here for setting the classpath: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html. And check here for finding jars downloaded by Maven: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-local-repository