# "Group pressure" in Maven's dependency management

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I am experiencing a problem with Maven where the library `com.google.guava` is being referenced about half a dozen times across multiple layers of transitive dependencies in my project **A**. Almost all of those dependencies require the age-old version `18.0`.

I have written another dependency **B** that is being used in project **A** as well.
This dependency directly depends on version `28.0` of `com.google.guava`, but Maven still chooses `18.0` over the much newer version.

Unless I explicitly include the newer version in all projects depending on **B**, the library will be nonfunctional due to `NoMethodError`s and such. If I do so I will probably experience problems with *all other libraries* because of the new, binary incompatible version of the dependency.

Effectively, I am experiencing group pressure to use the old version of the dependency because *everyone else does it*.

Why would Maven not choose the newest version instead?
What can I do to convince Maven to use the newer version in all projects depending on **B**?

Is there a way to separate concerns and have *all other dependencies* actually use `18.0` while my dependency uses `28.0`?

If just a slightly larger package size is the prize to pay for more modern libraries across the projects...

Maybe there is a possibility to hard-link a certain dependency version for my library **B**, so only my library uses the newer version?

Comment: Is your problem just at compile time or also at runtime? You will have problems having 2 different versions of the library in runtime. If the library supports retroactivity, you should use only the newer one. If not, you might be out of luck.

Comment: Depending on your project structure you might want to look into packaging **B** as a [fat jar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16222748/3419894) to see if it would suit your needs.

Comment: Is v28.0 backwards compatible to v18.0?

Answer (score 0):

In maven you can use `<dependencyManagement>`

With this tag you can explicitly tell maven which versions of dependencies you want your project to use.

For guava you can do something like:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>28.0</version>
        </dependency>

    ...
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Then you can do someghing like:

```
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    ...
    </dependencies>
```

This will force maven to use the guava 18 dependency

Comment: I guess you mean 28.0