# How to create Executeable war/jar for Spring boot Multi-Module project

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, multi-module

I'm trying to create a uber jar from spring boot multi module project. Example provided https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/

I've two modules:

```
  <modules>
    <module>library</module>
    <module>application</module>
</modules>
```

If I run "mvn clean install spring-boot:repackage" from "application" I see that application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war gets created. But once I open that war by 7-zip, I see there's nothing for the "Library" module under the WEB-INF folder. And apprantely, the generated war file doesn't work; 'cause it doesn't have any reference classes from "Library"
Here's is the parent pom:

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>multiModule</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent-multi-module</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>library</module>
    <module>application</module>
</modules>
<properties>
    <start-class>bismillah.application.DemoApplication</start-class>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

And finally the pom from "library" module:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>bismillah</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>library</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

And finally the pm from "application" module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>bismillah</groupId>
    <artifactId>application</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>application</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>bismillah</groupId>
            <artifactId>library</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                      </goals>
                    </execution>
                  </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

As you can see that I've used "repackage" goal from "spring-boot-maven-plugin"; but still not working. Not sure what am I doing wrong...
Can you please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building a fat jar using maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven), if not let know, we'll try to figure it out

Comment: @Hasan Could you try executing the command 'mvn clean install' only and not inlcude the repackage goal in the command as it is already specified in the pom while building the provject ?

Comment: similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70833195/spring-boot-multi-module-spring-boot-maven-plugin-compilation-failure/70833786#70833786

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the library module as a dependency of the application module pom in the  section

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).