# Is it possible to run a JavaFX jar in a enviroment where the openJRE has no java FX?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

We built a Jar (java 8) that runs with the Proper JDK and JRE. But on the client PCs is no suitable OpenJRE and because of policy reasons they only use a openJRE8 without jfxrt.jar (which is annoying).

Bacause of that, we can not run the JFX Jar like regular. But we can ship it with a suitable openJRE that contains jfx.

But for comfort reasons: is it possible to build the Jar in a way, in which the javaFX library is included/built into the Jar so we don't have to ship the whole enviroment ?

Comment: Would building a fat jar solve the problem? [Building a fat jar using Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven)

Comment: @ldz sadly not. we aslo tried launch4j but thats the same thing. we need to ship the enviroment

Answer (score 0):

With OpenJDK13, it is possible to include openjfx via maven dependencies, and then build a fat jar that includes the javafx libraries. Sadly, openjdk is not available for Java8

Comment: OpenJDK is availiable for java 8. Since Java 11 Oracle decided to treat JavaFX like any other library, a seperate Module. That works. But in Java 8 it seems like JavaFX depends on the Runtime jfxrt.jar . 
There are in Fact possibilities to have a OpenJDK 8 with java fx. But we can not use it because of policy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options to run a [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) ([OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io)) app. You need to have OpenJFX libraries: (a) within your app, (b) on the user’s classpath, or (c) bundled with a JVM installed on user’s local machine.

- Wrap a copy of the OpenJDX libraries within your app bundle. See tools such as jlink.

  - You would likely want to use the [Java Platform Module System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) to include a slimmed-down JDK as well. This makes for a completely self-contained double-clickable app that can launch like a native app.
- Put a copy of the OpenJFX libraries on the user's machine, on the [Java classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)) somewhere.
- Install a JDK on the user’s machine that includes a copy of the OpenJFX libraries. I know of two Java implementations that include those libraries:

  - LibericaFX from BellSoft
  - [ZuluFX](https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-enterprise/zulufx-faq/) from Azul Systems

Study:

- [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdatev2020may-6548840.pdf), published 2020-05-11 (version 1.01) by Oracle.
- [*Java Is Still Free*](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-2-0-0-6b9aa8d6d244), a white paper by pillars of the Java community.

Here is a flowchart to help choosing a Java implementation vendor. Notice the decision box at bottom for JavaFX/OpenJFX.

[image: Flowchart guiding you in choosing a vendor for a Java 11 implementation]