# Maven assembly plugin is not including the project packages

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to build a fat jar with maven assembly plugin for distributing a desktop application.
My POM looks like

```
<build>

    <!-- To parse properties files under resources folder : -->
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.acme.qpguard.editor.Application</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

The command mvn assembly: single is creating a fat jar with other dependencies, but fat jar does no include my classes.

So while starting the jar, I'm getting an error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.acme.qpguard.editor.Application
```

How can I fix my POM so that it includes my project files too

Please note that the project is running fine in Eclipse.

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-mave

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Mayur and @Randy Casburn. Your pointers definitely helped me in finding a fix using maven shaded plugin.

I'm posting the fix as someone may find this useful at a later point of time

```
    <build>
    <!-- To parse properties files under resources folder : -->
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>

                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>

                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.acme.qpguard.editor.Application</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Note: I have to apply a filter for removing signature files from some jars as it was breaking the execution.