# Issue using Dockerfile with Java and Maven as build tool

Tags: java, docker, maven

I have an issue running a docker container. I am using Java 17 with Maven.

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17 as builder

WORKDIR /workdir
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src


RUN mvn package -DskipTests


FROM openjdk:17.0-jdk-slim

COPY --from=builder /workdir/target/myproj-*.jar /myproj.jar


CMD ["java" , "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "/myproj.jar"]
```

The below pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.myproj</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproj</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>myproj</name>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hellokaton</groupId>
        <artifactId>blade-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.myproj.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And finally the below main class:

```
package com.myproj;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.hellokaton.blade.Blade;


public class App 
{
    public static void main(String[] args )
    {
        try {
            Blade blade = Blade.create();
            blade.start();
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

When I run the below commands on docker:

```
docker build . --tag gcr.io/myproj-c39b9/myproj 
docker run -d -p 80:80 gcr.io/myproj-c39b9/myproj
```

I get this error

```
2023-02-08 08:19:58 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hellokaton/blade/Blade
2023-02-08 08:19:58 at com.myproj.App.main(App.java:14)
2023-02-08 08:19:58 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hellokaton.blade.Blade
2023-02-08 08:19:58 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
2023-02-08 08:19:58 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
2023-02-08 08:19:58 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
2023-02-08 08:19:58 ... 1 more
```

I am not sure what is missing here. I would guess it is something related to classpath setting.

I need your usual support please.

Thank you

Comment: Hi! Does you app run if you execute the CMD outside docker? `java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar ./myproj.jar`

Comment: You aren't providing runtime dependencies. You can use the [maven-shade-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16222965/2970947) to build a "fat" (or [uber](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)) jar.

Answer (score 0):

For quick image building/less CVEs use:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17.0.10_7-jdk-jammy
```

and change:

```
RUN mvn package -DskipTests
```

to

```
RUN mvn install -DskipTests
```

Using `mvn install` in your Dockerfile is important because it not only compiles and packages your application but also installs the resulting artifacts (JAR) into the local Maven repository. This is crucial for building Docker images since the installed JAR is needed to run the application within the container, ensuring that the required dependencies are available during runtime

Comment: Is this a solution? Please add more information to this answer

Comment: Sorry, I rewrite the answer !