# Get only the Jar from maven repository through build.gradle file

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build.gradle, maven-repository

I need to use a Jar from a remote repository.
I am providing the dependency details in the dependencies section in build.gradle like this -

```
compile("com.rhuldip.artifactId:com.rhuldip.projectId:1-SNAPSHOT")
```

But in my remote repository there are 3 files maven-metadata.xml,com.rhuldip.projectId-1-SNAPSHOT.jar and com.rhuldip.projectId-1-SNAPSHOT.pom.
com.rhuldip.projectId-1-SNAPSHOT.pom contains multiple dependencies which i dont need in my project.

I just need com.rhuldip.projectId-1-SNAPSHOT.jar in my project. Is there any way i can get only the specified jar and not the pom dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

Your jar, and your project, will **not** work without the other dependencies.

You need to read the documentation on [transitive dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_terminology.html#sub:terminology_transitive_dependency).

**Updates**:

Maven assumes that all jars are thin-jars, and therefore it always reads the accompanying pom to determine what other dependencies it needs to download.

For your case, if you are using a fat-jar, you have two options:

1. If you control building of the fat-jar, it should be named differently: something like projectId-jar-with-dependencies-1-SNAPSHOT, with appropriately named pom. Have a look at [Building a fat jar using maven](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16222748/3124333).
2. If you do not control building of the fat jar, you could download it manually into your project, and then install it from Maven. Have a look at [How to add local jar files to a Maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4955635/3124333)

Comment: Its a fat Jar so transitive dependencies are not required.

Comment: @RAHULDEEP See updates.