# Deployed jar get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument

Tags: spring-boot, deployment, pom.xml, pdfbox, executable-jar

I have a spring boot application that uses external jars present in a folder at the same level as the src folder, when I launch the application everything works, but when I create the jar ( maven clean compile package ) and launch it from another system

```bash
java -jar application.jar
```

I get this error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
```

this is a part of my pom

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.digidoc4j.dss</groupId>
            <artifactId>dss-pades-pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>5.11.1.d4j.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox-xmpbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.29</version>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/xmpbox-2.0.29.jar</systemPath>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.29</version>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/pdfbox-tools-2.0.29.jar</systemPath>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox-examples</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.29</version>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/pdfbox-examples-2.0.29.jar</systemPath>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.29</version>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/pdfbox-2.0.29.jar</systemPath>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.29</version>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/fontbox-2.0.29.jar</systemPath>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar</systemPath>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: You need to have these jar files on that other system too. Btw you don't need pdfbox-examples. These are examples to learn from the source code.

Comment: I need to distribute my jar to all systems that have java installed, my jar should include libraries (other jars) and dependencies inside it

Comment: That's a very different topic, you want a "fat jar". See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven/16222965#16222965

Comment: I created a "fat jar" but the error continues to exist, inside the jar I find the path org/apache/pdfbox but it does not contain the PDDocument class, inside that folder there is only the preflight folder

Comment: You should create a different question related to the shading plugin. Alternatively, use pdfbox-app , this usually contains all you need.